# Jquery UI Tabs access ui.tab outside of .tabs()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using Jquery UI Tabs loading ajax content and I'm wondering how to retrieve:

```
$.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
```

outside of .tabs()

Actually I do so:

```
$("#boards").tabs({
    select : function(event, ui) {
              $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
    },
});
```

But I want to access ui.tab outside of .tabs() is possible? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a variable outside of that `select` function, which you set inside of it. This should not be a global variable, unless absolutely neccessary though. And keep in mind that the `select` function must have been called before at least once, before you can access that variable (because it is set inside the function, not before).
That would result in something like this:

```
/* This is not recommended to be a global context */

var myUiTabVariable;
$("#boards").tabs({
    select : function(event, ui) {
        myUiTabVariable = ui.tab;
        MyFunction();
    }
});

function MyFunction() {
    //Here you can use the ui.tab varible outside of the select function
    console.log(myUiTabVariable);
}
```

Once again, remember that you should not call `MyFunction` unless the `select` function has been called at least once. Otherwise `myUiTabVariable` would be undefined.

Comment: i think that I should pass myUiTabVariable to the function but it should work, i'll investigate and if will work check the answere, for now I gave you a +1

Comment: it works but I need to use it independent from the select event

Comment: well i have no idea how and why you would want to use that object independently. it is an argument generated by the select event of the tabs-widget. it should only be used in connection with an occuring select-event. Maybe you should edit your original question, describing a little more in detail what you are trying to accomplish, we might help you more efficiently then :)

Comment: reading better Jquery UI Tabs docs I find out that ui.tab is avalaible when interacting with the interface so there's no way